# AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute '_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT'

Tags: sockets, tcpclient, tcpserver, ros2

I'm trying to build a Python socket on ROS2 to communicate with an external non-ROS2 server.
However, I get some build errors when I try to build it.
The error is:

```
AttributeError: module 'socket' has no attribute '_GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT'
```

I'm confused if the build error is related to ROS2 or whether I have something mistaken on the code.Any advice would be appreciated

I tried initializing by adding a timeout, however, I wasn't able to solve the issue:

```py
class MySocket:
    def __init__(self, sock=None, timeout=socket._GLOBAL_DEFAULT_TIMEOUT):
        if sock is None:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        else:
            self.sock = sock
        self.host = "192.168.X.XXX"
        self.port = 8
        self.MSGLEN = 1024
        self.timeout = timeout
```

The code snippet of the socket I am trying to build on my ROS2 is

```py
import socket

class MySocket:
    def __init__(self, sock=None):
        if sock is None:
            self.sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        else:
            self.sock = sock
        self.host = "192.168.X.XXX"
        self.port = 8
        self.MSGLEN = 1024

    def connect(self):
        self.sock.connect((self.host, self.port))

    def send(self, msg):
        if len(msg) != 1:
            raise ValueError("Accepting only the valid commands")
        totalsent = 0
        while totalsent < 1:
            sent = self.sock.send(msg.encode())
            if sent == 0:
                raise RuntimeError("Socket connection broken")
            totalsent += sent

    def distSend(self, msg):
        if not isinstance(msg, (int, float)):
            raise ValueError("Accepting only valid numeric values")
        msg_str = str(msg)
        totalsent = 0
        while totalsent < len(msg_str):
            sent = self.sock.send(msg_str[totalsent:].encode())
            if sent == 0:
                raise RuntimeError("Socket connection broken")
            totalsent += sent

    def receive(self):
        received_char = self.sock.recv(1).decode()
        if not received_char:
            raise RuntimeError("Socket connection broken")
        return received_char


def main():
    client = MySocket()
    client.connect()
    client.send('M')
    client.receive()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```